# Why don't my .jsp files work with Spring Boot using Spring MVC

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I've spent the entire day trying to get a simple Spring Boot application to show my .jsp files. I can't switch to another technology (requirements) and I can't get it to work. It's a very simple application. Here's the file structure:

```
pom.xml
src/
  main/
    java/
      hello/
        HelloController.java
        MVCApplication.java
    resources/
      application.properties
      static/
        index.html
      templates/
        pages/
          helloworld.jsp
```

Here are my two java files:

HelloController.java:

```
// @RestController // From when I first posted this question. 
@Controller
public class HelloController {

  // Should I add a "produces" attribute to this? I don't know what to use for jsp.
  @RequestMapping("/hello")
  public String hello(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("greeting", "Hello Spring MVC");
    // I see this message in the output, so I know this method is getting called.
    System.err.printf("Setting \"greeting\" to \"Hello Spring MVC\"%n");
    return "helloworld";
  }
}
```

MVCApplication.java:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MVCApplication extends SpringApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(MVCApplication.class, args);
  }

  // Since I have the properties spring.mvc.view.prefix and spring.mvc.view.suffix
  // defined in applications.properties, I don't think I need this method.
  // I have tried it both with and without this method. It doesn't work either way.
  @Bean
  public ViewResolver getViewResolver() {
    // I see this line in the output, which confirms that this method gets called.
    System.err.printf("Creating custom JSP View Resolver%n"); // NON-NLS
    InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("/templates/pages/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
    return resolver;
  }
}
```

My helloworld.jsp file is very simple, but I never see it in the browser:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Spring MVC -HelloWorld</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Greeting: ${greeting}</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

I have defined three properties in applications.properties.

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/templates/pages/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp

server.port=7070
```

I know the properties are getting read, because I need to specify port 7070 in my browser to see anything. So all these properties should be working.

My pom file seems to have all the right dependencies.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation=
"http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>gs-spring-boot</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>

        <parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
        </parent>

        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            </dependency>

            <!--JSP Enabled: -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>

        <properties>
            <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        </properties>

        <packaging>jar</packaging>

        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>

    </project>
```

The templates directory used to be called WEB-INF, but I read somewhere that WEB-INF doesn't work well with Spring Boot. But it doesn't work either way.

I go to localhost:7070/hello, and all that I get is an error message:

***There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
/templates/pages/helloworld.jsp***

This tells me that my controller method is getting called, but it's either not finding my .jsp file, or it's not even looking for it.

I've looked at a lot of similar questions on this forum, and so far, nothing has helped. People have made suggestions like switching to thymeleaf, which is probably fine for other people, but it's not an option for me. Can anybody figure out what I'm doing wrong?

---

Addendum:

At Vipul Singh's suggestion, I tried changing the controller method to this:

```
@RequestMapping("/hello")
public ModelAndView hello(Model theModel) {
  // theModel.addAttribute("greeting", "Hello Spring MVC");  // this didn't work.
  ModelAndView modelView= new ModelAndView("helloworld", "helloworld", theModel);
  modelView.addObject("greeting", "Hello Spring MVC"); // This didn't work either.
  return modelView;
}
```

It didn't work. I got the same error message as before.

*Revised version. Originally I used @RestController, which was wrong. I also reduced the spring.boot.starter.parent version from 1.5.7 to 1.5.2*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem turned out to be a combination of things, but the most important details were how I packaged the application and how I launched it. The Spring Documentation says (https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.0.M5/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-jsp-limitations) to package the files as a .war file, claiming that a .jar file won't work. It turns out that a .jar file occasionally worked, but a .war file always worked. But the application needs to be launched from that file, rather than from the class files on disk that my IDE builds. Once I started launching it from the packaged war file, it started to work.

That said, there were various suggestions about how to write the mapping method, and they all seem to work fine, so that wasn't the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Change this:

```
@RestController
```

to this:

```
@Controller
```

You have declared your controller as REST one so by default, responses are "vieweless". Usually it is used when you want to reutrn JSON serialized responses like you do.

What you want to use is full stack Sping MVC, and controller from `MVC` here is component annotated with @Controller`.

Also remember, that if controller returns `String` it must be either a `redirect:` `forward:` or (i guess in your case` name of template to render.

Comment: Can you explain your answer?

Comment: Changing `@RestController` to `@Controller` leaves me with no way to map the request to my methods. (I tried it.) Even if I separate the Controller from the Rest interface, which sounds like a good idea, I still need to map the input to a method, and return a value that will get interpreted as a .jsp file name. Your statement makes sense, but a code example would be helpful.

Comment: @MiguelMunoz *Changing @RestController to @Controller leaves me with no way to map the request to my methods.* Why is that? `@RequestMappings` will work the same in both cases.

Comment: Good question. When I first tried it, it didn't work. Now it seems to be working, although I'm not seeing my jsp pages. However, in place of the String, I'm now getting an error message that suggests it's looking for a jsp file with the correct name. I still have a few issues to work out, but it looks like I'm making progress.

Comment: Your suggestion got me closer to the target, but it still misses. Now I get an error message saying this: "There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404). /templates/pages/helloworld.jsp" So it's searching for the .jsp file at the correct path, but it's not finding it. I've verified, using Class.getResourceAsStream(), that the file has the correct path, but it still doesn't work. As far as I can tell, it must have something to do with the way Spring Boot configures things, but I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

try replacing your code with this it will work out.
  How it works.
when you hit the browser with some URL like https://xxx/yyy/hello some thing like this you will trigger this controller now this controller will load your jsp page which is `helloworld` which is called by the `viewHolder`, now we create object of ModelAndView and pass the value as per our requirement and `viewHolder` will incorporate the values and pass it back to the controller and then controller then pass it back to user as a response.

```
 @Controller
    public class HelloController {

      // Should I add a "produces" attribute to this? I don't know what to use for jsp.
      @RequestMapping("/hello")
      public getForm() {
        ModelAndView model= new ModelAndView("helloworld");
        model.addObject("greeting", "Hello Spring MVC");
        return model;
      }
    }
```

you can also write this function as a string type.

```
@Controller
    public class HelloController {
@RequestMapping("/hello")
      public string getForm(ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttributes("greeting", "Hello Spring MVC");
        return "helloworld";
      }
    }
```

if it is still not working check your spring dispatcher servlet and web xml if it defined properly.
some thing like this should be there in spring dispatcher servlet.

```
<bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">

        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>

    </bean>
```

WEB-INF is my root folder inside src and views is the folder which contains the jsp pages

Comment: Your code doesn't compile. Where you say: [public ModelAndView hello("helloworld") { ] you pass a value where you should declare a parameter. That said, I tried something similar. I declared a parameter of type Model, and passed it to the constructor of the ModelAndView. Then I tried adding the attribute name/value, returning the modelAndView. I tried this both on the model and the modelAndView. Neither worked. In both cases the browser gave me this message: There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
/templates/pages/helloworld.jsp. But you may be on the right track.

Comment: I have updated the answer with proper explanation, hope this helps

Comment: Are you using Maven to build? Because Maven doesn't seem to expect to find WEB-INF in the src folder. When I put it there, it doesn't show up in the jar file after I do a build.

Also, are you using Spring Boot? The task here isn't how to get jsp files to work. It's getting them to work inside Spring Boot. I don't think Spring Boot is supposed to need a web.xml file, and if it is, I'm not sure where I should put it.

Comment: yes I am using MAVEN to configure my project and build.

Comment: Thank you. So my next two questions are these: 1) How do you get it to accept the include the WEB-INF folder in your jar file. 2) Are you using Spring Boot?